# How to type into a UITextView inside a XCTestCase

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

How do you type into a `UITextView` inside a `XCTestCase`? The `UITextView` is the first responder so it already had focus and the keyboard is up.

I've tried:

```
app.typeText("footer")
app.textViews.element(boundBy: 0).typeText("foobar")
app.links.element(boundBy: 0).typeText("foobar")
```

for some reason `app.textViews.count` always returns `0`?

Comment: Is your text view inside a container view? What's the view hierarchy like?

Comment: @Oletha, it's inside a stack. The stack is the top most view.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not that `.typeText(_:)` doesn't work, it's that your query doesn't resolve to an element.

It can sometimes seem like the query is not working properly when the view you're trying to find is inside an accessible container view of some sort. You can mitigate this by explicitly disabling accessibility in the container view.

Set the stack view that contains the text view to not be an accessibility element and then set an accessibility identifier on the text view.

```
// app code
let stack: UIStackView!
let textView: UITextView!
stack.isAccessibilityElement = false
textView.isAccessibilityElement = true
textView.accessibilityIdentifier = "myTextView"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textView = app.textViews["myTextView"]
textView.typeText("something")
```

Comment: Given that `UIStackView` doesn't display any info or support user interaction *per se*, why Apple would make it an accessible element by default? If this is indeed the case, wouldn't this result in all sorts of accessibility issues, way beyond UI tests, given how useful/popular `UIStackView` is?

Comment: Accessibility for end users works slightly differently to accessibility for XCTest. I've had quite niche examples where views inside tables are inaccessible to tests but not to Voiceover...

Comment: Ok, wasn't aware of that discrepancy... anyway, the `UITableView` container, as opposed to `UIStackView`, supports user interactions (scrolling, etc) so this wouldn't surprise me as much ;)

Comment: Coming back to this recently, this doesn't work for me. I continue to be able to resolve the query into an element.

Comment: Just because the query returns an XCUIElement object, doesn't meant that that element will be found to exist at runtime. The query may or may not resolve to a single XCUIElement at runtime and cause errors.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting an unique *[accessibility identifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification/1623132-accessibilityidentifier)* for your `UITextView` and then:

```
let textView = app.textViews["uniqueId"]
XCTAssert(textView.exists, "uniqueId text view NOT FOUND")
textView.tap()
textView.typeText("foobar")
```

Comment: This also does not work. Do you have this working in your own code?

Comment: What's more this returns 0: `app.children(matching: .textView).count`

Comment: @Mystic Works great for `UITextField`, so I can't see why it won't work for `UITextView` as well. I added an extra *assert* just to be safe...

Comment: ...you could try to *record* the UI test instead to see if Xcode can find your text view for you ;) (This is done by the *red button* on the bottom.)

Comment: Try it and let me know how it goes. I find that the code that the recorder gives code that doesn't behave correctly. I know how to do it for the UITextField, if the UITextView behaved like the UITextField I wouldn't have a problem.